# Can $a*b*c*d = d*a*b*c$ be true without associative property?

Tags: arithmetic

Let * be an operation on a set S where the operation * has commutative property but not associative property.

**Is $((a*b)*c)*d = ((d*a)*b)*c$ true?**

Comment: what does $\ast$ means? usual multiplication? convolution?

Comment: What does $a\ast b\ast c\ast d$ mean without associativity?

Comment: "*by associativity*"  "*by commutativity*"... What is $*$ in the first place?  If it is an arbitrary binary operation, then it need not necessarily be associative or commutative to begin with.  If it is not associative, then what does $a*b*c*d$ mean to begin with?  The notation is underspecified.  If $*$ was only defined as a binary operation, and not a quaternary operation... then $a*b*c*d$ is undefined and should have been written with enough parentheses to make it clear in what order it is being applied, e.g. as $((a*b)*c)*d$.

Comment: If you do mean for $*$ to be the usual multiplication... then what do you mean "*without associative property*"?  The usual multiplication *is* associative, you can't take that away from it.

Comment: @JMoravitz $*$ is the usual multiplication on real numbers. I was not trying to take associative property away from the usual multiplication. I was just wondering if $a*b*c*d$ = $(b*c*d)*a could be true if it were not to have associative property. Also, I will edit the question to clarify the order of the multiplications

Comment: "*Can it be true*" is not the same thing as "*Is it always true*".  Can it?  Yes, the real multiplication is an example.  Is it always?  No, certainly not.

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz I will edit the question so that the operation is an arbitrary binary operation with commutative property but without associative property.

Comment: Let $*$ be a binary operation on $\{0,1,2\}$ such that $x*y = \begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=2~\text{or }y=2\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  Then note that $x*y$ is commutative but not associative.  Here, let $a=b=c=1$ and $d=2$, you would have $((a*b)*c)*d=((1*1)*1)*2=0$ but $((d*a)*b)*c=((2*1)*1)*1=1$

Comment: How about this meaning:  Take the usual list of axioms for the real numbers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Axioms  Omit the associative law for multiplication.  From that can we prove $((ab)c)d = ((da)b)c)$?

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for your answer and your patience.